# Docker compose deploy in a remote server

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, remote-access

I'm trying to deploy a docker image to a remote server using docker-compose but I'm getting authentication issue:

Command:

```
docker-compose -H "ssh://root@host_ip" --tlscacert "~/.ssh/private_key" ps
```

Output:

```
sudo docker-compose -H "ssh://root@jenkins.evercam.io" --tlscacert "~/.ssh/id_jenkins" -f evercam_camera_server/docker-compose.yml ps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 123, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 69, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 132, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 164, in __init__
  File "docker/transport/sshconn.py", line 113, in __init__
  File "docker/transport/sshconn.py", line 121, in _connect
  File "paramiko/client.py", line 446, in connect
  File "paramiko/client.py", line 764, in _auth
  File "paramiko/client.py", line 740, in _auth
  File "paramiko/transport.py", line 1580, in auth_publickey
  File "paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 250, in wait_for_response
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
[28861] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

```
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192
docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
ubuntu version 18.04
```

I tried with a recent version of docker compose which is 1.28.5 it's able to access the given host, but strangely it's asking the password five times!

Comment: Your ssh private key is neither TLS-related nor a CA certificate; the [`docker` base command documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/) doesn't suggest any options to provide ssh keys.  You might find it easier to `ssh root@remote docker-compose ...` without using the `docker -H` transport option.

Comment: I tried the same with ubuntu 20.04 and it's working fine

Comment: @DavidMaze I beleive you are right, I tried it using ssh agent and it worked, thanks!